# Unable to install @angular/cli Error npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2:

Tags: angular

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://git
hub.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Nagesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\
ng
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Nagesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\Nagesh\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng' -> 'C:\Users\Nagesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
.ps1'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Nagesh\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nagesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-04-14T05_28_53
_373Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated warning has nothing to do with the issue you have. The real error message is just below that. My guess is it's a permission problem with your NodeJs installation. You should try removing your NodeJs installation completely and reinstall and then try again.

Or better yet, install NVM to manage you NodeJs instances.

For Mac/Linux: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm
For Windows: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

After installing NVM use following command to install Angular CLI:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

It should work fine. Hope that helps

Comment: It doesn't work. When you try to generate a project it will download the deprecated package and exit with an error at that point.